# Separate files for inline media queries using sass?

Tags: css, sass

I would like to know if it is possible using SASS to have a separate file for each media query (mobile, tablet, desktop etc.), and then using inline media queries have sass compile the inline media query for that class to that specific file?

For example:

Say I have a sass partial _article.scss.

```
.test-class {
      color: #000000;
      background: red;
      width: 980px;

  @media only screen and (max-width : 300px) {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
}
```

This partial is imported in base.scss.

```
@import "partials/article";
```

Now what I want is that instead of each media query being compiled in the base.css file, I want each specific media query relating to mobile, tablet etc to be compiled to its own file (mobile.css, tablet,css etc).

In other words I want the benefits of inline media queries, while still having a very modular file structure for each device. When I serve the files I then only have to server 2 small files (base.css and mobile.css).

Is this possible? I am currently just creating a mobile.scss file and then manually overriding the styles which in a project as large as I am working in will lead to problems later down the line.

Is there a better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that every single CSS file linked from the document will get downloaded by every client, even if they don't meet the media conditions, right?  There's no performance benefit to doing this.

Comment: yes, I realize this. The reason I want to do this is because it is easier to understand(logically) especially since other clients will be using these files on their own websites which are part of the company. Also if we wanted to it is possible to only serve the required files using javascript and having a fallback.

Comment: @cimmanon Actually there is. By google's PageSpeed Insights documentation, the css included and defined by media="prientation:portrait" (or other tags as 'print'..etc) is considered as 'non-blocking' and hence it will not block the render of the LAYOUT, before it is painted. Thus it is a performance boost. Usually you do such things when you go deep into the performance of the web page and want the SEO to like you - even more.

Answer (score -4):

You can do this with jQuery:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 777) {
        $(".body").attr("href", "css/small.css");
    } else if ((width >= 778) && (width < 980)) {
        $(".body").attr("href", "css/medium.css");
    } else {
       $(".body").attr("href", "css/big.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

and a better way would be to include a list of devices and then include your CSS sheets, that way you won't have a double download, meaning you will download ONLY if the device matches. For this purpose, you can use any of the languages at [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) and then adapt to your liking.

Comment: Does not answer the question.  The OP wants to take a single Sass file and have it generate multiple CSS files, broken out by media query.

Comment: yes you're correct, sometimes I confuse usability and what works with the forms, rules and protocol of who knows what. Sorry, my bad.